# animate function works in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I have a centered div and 4 other divs - one on each side of the centered div. When I click a button each of the div slide into the frame and push the centered div out.

It works fine in chrome but fails using firefox, leaving me with no error from firebug.

[Here](http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/index.html) is my implementation which doesn't currently work correctly in firefox.

As you can see, in firefox the centered div simply disappears instead of sliding out of the screen. Using chrome, the centered div slides out as intended.

Can someone take a look with firebug and tell me what they think might be causing the problem?

This code was based off of a jsfiddle that works fine using either chrome or firefox.

Here is the code to the jsfiddle:

here is the **html**

```
<div id="fullContainer">
    <div id="right">

    </div>
    <div id="left">

    </div>
    <div id="top">

    </div>
    <div id="bottom">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="centerContainer">
    <div id="relativeContainer">
        <div id="content">
            This is where your face should go.  Notice that I placed it within a centering div.  
            This will enable the face to be absolutely positioned, and allow for you to modify 
            it's position when the side-bars slide in.
            <div data-move="left">Open Left</div>
            <div data-move="right">Open Right</div>
            <div data-move="top">Open Top</div>
            <div data-move="bottom">Open Bottom</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the **css**

```
#centerContainer {
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
#relativeContainer {
    position:relative;
}
#fullContainer {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    top:-200px;
    left:-150px;
    background:#BADA55;
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#content.right {
    left:-250px;
}
#content.left {
    left:-50px;
}
#content.bottom {
    top:-300px;
}
#content.top {
    top:-100px;
}

#content div {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
    margin-top:15px;
    text-align:center;
}
#left {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-125px;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#left.opened {
    left:0;
}

#right {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-125px;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    background:green;
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#right.opened {
    right:0;
}

#top {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:-125px;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#top.opened {
    top:0;
}

#bottom {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:-125px;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#bottom.opened {
    bottom:0;
}
```

here is the **javascript**:

```
function SlideOut(element){

    $(".opened").removeClass("opened");
    $("#"+element).addClass("opened");
    $("#content").removeClass().addClass(element);

}
$("#content div").click(function(){

    var move = $(this).attr('data-move');

    SlideOut(move);

});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WVPDH/2/)

Thank you

katie

Comment: Try clicking on the forehead? What's that? In Firefox, I can click all 4 links and they work fine for me...

Comment: im sorry i was referring to the second link - the jsfiddle works fine on both browsers

Comment: Your page has different JS than what you post and your fiddle. In the fiddle (and above) you use `$("#content div").click` but on your page you use `$("#content div").toggle` and define an `id` variable that I don't see you ever using, then call another anonymous function that removes `.opened` everywhere and removes all classes from `#content`. Potentially this could be creating some confusion.

Comment: @peter as for the id function that is in development so ignore that but the animation should occur when classes are removed from content. i changed the toggle back to click and still have the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Your test example is throwing a 404. Could you please put it in a JSFiddle that way we can see it in a sterile environment.

Comment: sorry I put the right page back up - i changed the page from test.html to index.html and forgot to change it here - sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing and found out what's happening. This is reproduced in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GRSM/) for illustration and demonstration purposes.

In Firefox if you are transitioning the CSS attribute `left`, it needs to have an initial value to start from. If it doesn't then it won't transition, it'll just assign the value to the attribute.

In Chrome if you don't have the initial value set it apparently just starts from wherever it is and doesn't worry about it.

If you check out the above fiddle in Firefox and click on the first row, it just appears farther over, while the second row transitions over. Only difference is the second row has a `left: 0` initially set. On Chrome both work the same.

If you put a `left: 0` on your `#content div` then it will slide like it should in Firefox. (Tested in Firebug and that does fix it).

Comment: can you help me with something else that is occurring now - when i slide the center div to the left the div doesn't slide out any more 
try the website again but this time click on the left eye

Comment: Without taking the whole page apart, using `left: 1150px` instead of `right: -1150px` for the `.left` class seems to fix it.