# jQuery slide animation of 'left' property working in Chrome and Safari, not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, browser, safari, cross-browser

I'm working on my personal site and having some trouble with an animation.

http://raddevon.github.io/personal-site/

https://github.com/raddevon/personal-site/tree/dev

Each of the project rows has an arrow next to the text. When clicked, it should change the left position of the image to push it out of the viewport and move the text to occupy the full width of the page.

This works wonderfully in Chrome. In Safari, the animation works, but it creates space to the right for rows that slide right even with `overflow` set to `hidden` for the row. In Firefox, however, the animation never happens. The arrow is swapped out (left for right and vise versa), but the sliding never occurs.

At first, I had no initial `left` value set for the sliding elements. After finding [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113107/animate-function-works-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox), I added those thinking that might be the problem (`position` is `relative` so I set the starting `left` at `0`), but I still cannot get the slide to work in FF. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't see any arrows anywhere on http://raddevon.github.io/personal-site/ ...

Comment: @BorisZbarsky So, you don't have the arrows I've pointed out here? http://monosnap.com/image/IizhLM7kSyKnw8E0g6CVXZfMk Do you have JS enabled in your browser?

Comment: Yeah, definitely don't have arrows there, in Firefox, Safari, or Opera.  And yes, JS is enabled in all of those.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky That's really strange. I get the arrows no matter which browser I use. It's only the animation that's giving me trouble. Are you doing anything that might disable embedded fonts? I'm using an icon font for the arrows.

Comment: Apart from using a Mac, no.